# NetworkX does not show edge label for edge to the same node

Tags: python, networkx

I discovered a strange behavior with the NetworkX graph drawing library: it does not draw the edge label if the edge leads backwards to the same node.

I'm pretty sure that it is a NetworkX feature, because I create all the edge labels with the same method and it works fine with non-looping edges, as you can see in the image.

Is there any display option that can help to display all edge labels?

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = nx.DiGraph()

edge_labels = dict()

g.add_edge(0, 1 )
#ATTENTION - this will work
edge_labels[(0, 1)] = '01'

g.add_edge(0, 0)

#ATTENTION - this line will not work
edge_labels[(0, 0)] = '00'

pos = nx.spring_layout(g)
nx.draw(g, pos, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(g, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels, 
font_color='red')
plt.show()
```

**Solved**
by putting '_____' before the string for the looping edge, it is how you can see it.
Is not pretty, but displays

```
        if state_id == self.last_parent.id:#if it is loop
        self.edge_labels[(self.last_parent.id, state_id)] = '_____'+ char_of_edge# add to the edge label the symbols
```

Example:

[image: Image example]

Comment: Can you create a small sample with code?

Comment: check that. The edge_labels[(0, 0)] = '00' is not working

Comment: Hey, that's cool that you found a workaround—can you please post it as an answer instead of editing it into your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the coordinates of two nodes `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` the label position is computed as

```
(x, y) = (
            x1 * label_pos + x2 * (1.0 - label_pos),
            y1 * label_pos + y2 * (1.0 - label_pos),
        )
```

where `label_pos` has a default value of `0.5`  [[source]](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/main/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py#L1137).
This means that the edge label for a self-edge overlaps with the node position and this is why you cannot see it, unless increasing the font size.

Comment: can i somehow change this position or extend this code somehow?